# I don't know how to create sql query api php?

Tags: php, api

I don't know how to create android api php.If you know please let me know.`Menu table` this is `Subcategory` this is `tbl_recipes` this is detail page this is how to prepare api with this.how to use left joining with this.`Menu,Subcategory ,tbl_recipes` How to bring joining with these 3 tables i am new devloper

Menu table this

```
INSERT INTO `menu` (`mid`, `menu_Name`, `menu_icon`) VALUES
(1, 'dfhg', '4198-2022-08-18.png'),
(2, 'husfushdf', '9619-2022-08-18.jpeg'),
(3, 'asf', '0356-2022-08-17.png'),
```

Subcategory this

```
 INSERT INTO `tbl_category` (`cid`, `category_name`, `category_image`, `menu_id`) VALUES
(25, 'dfg', '3523-2022-08-23.png', 12),
(26, 'tytry', '6412-2022-08-23.png', 13);
```

this details page

```
 INSERT INTO `tbl_recipes` (`recipe_id`, `cat_id`, `recipe_title`, `menu_id`, `recipe_description`, `recipe_image`, `video_url`, `video_id`, `content_type`, `size`, `featured`, `tags`, `total_views`, `last_update`) VALUES
(47, 0, 'dsg', 0, '<p>sg</p>\r\n', '1661254132_Screenshot (6).png', '', 'cda11up', 'Post', '', 0, '0', 0, '2022-08-23 11:28:52'),
(48, 14, 'sad', 0, '<p>asdasd</p>\r\n', '1661254498_Ent-card-1.jpg', '', 'cda11up', 'Post', '', 0, '0', 0, '2022-08-23 18:57:49'),
(49, 25, 'fgh', 13, '<p>fghfgh</p>\r\n', '1661280418_Screenshot (5).png', '', 'cda11up', 'Post', '', 0, '0', 0, '2022-08-23 18:57:44'),
(50, 25, 'try', 13, '<p>tyt</p>\r\n', '1661281058_Screenshot (5).png', '', 'cda11up', 'Post', '', 1, '0', 0, '2022-08-23 18:57:54');
```

Query tried

```
$query_menu = "SELECT DISTINCT c.cid, c.category_name, c.category_image, COUNT(DISTINCT r.recipe_id) as recipes_count FROM tbl_category c LEFT JOIN tbl_recipes r ON c.cid = r.cat_id GROUP BY c.cid ORDER BY c.cid DESC LIMIT $limit";
```

Comment: Have you tried any code or tutorial

Comment: This is not a searchable/helpful title.  It relates to thousands of questions here.  Please [edit] to be more specific.  If this is a PHP question, I expect to see some PHP effort.  However, this looks like a SQL/MYSQL question.

Comment: @Shibon $query_menu = "SELECT DISTINCT c.cid, c.category_name, c.category_image, COUNT(DISTINCT r.recipe_id) as recipes_count
         FROM tbl_category c LEFT JOIN tbl_recipes r ON c.cid = r.cat_id GROUP BY c.cid ORDER BY c.cid DESC LIMIT $limit";  how add to menu subscategory,table_recipes tables

Comment: Find the [edit] question button.  Do not provide question details as comments.

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: Please share your PHP code too

Comment: @Shibon  1.menu category 2. sub category 3.sub category click view recipe datails how to write query

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24cfe1/9/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below SQL query

```
select tbl_recipes.*, tbl_category.category_name, tbl_category.category_image, menu.menu_name, menu.menu_icon from tbl_recipes
left join tbl_category on tbl_recipes.cat_id=tbl_category.cid
left join menu on tbl_recipes.menu_id=menu.mid
```

Comment: 1.menu category 2. sub category 3.sub category click view recipe datails  how to write

Comment: please share expected response

Comment: $query_menu = "SELECT DISTINCT  m.mid ,menu_Name,menu_icon,c.cid, c.category_name, c.category_image, COUNT(DISTINCT r.recipe_id) as recipes_count FROM tbl_category c LEFT JOIN tbl_recipes r ON c.cid = r.cat_id GROUP BY c.cid ORDER BY c.cid DESC LIMIT $limit"; how add to menu ,subscategory,table_recipes tables

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT m.mid, m.menu_Name, m.menu_icon, c.cid, c.category_name, c.category_image, COUNT(DISTINCT r.recipe_id) as recipes_count FROM tbl_category c LEFT JOIN tbl_recipes r ON c.cid = r.cat_id left join menu m on m.mid=r.menu_id GROUP BY c.cid ORDER BY c.cid DESC LIMIT $limit

Comment: Try this: SELECT DISTINCT m.mid, m.menu_Name, m.menu_icon, c.cid, c.category_name, c.category_image, COUNT(DISTINCT r.recipe_id) as recipes_count FROM tbl_category c LEFT JOIN tbl_recipes r ON c.cid = r.cat_id left join menu m on m.mid=c.menu_id GROUP BY c.cid ORDER BY c.cid DESC LIMIT $limit

Comment: only category show subcategory not show

Comment: You mentioned only 3 tables menu, tbl_category, tbl_recipes. Where is subcategory table and it's relation with these 3 tables?

Comment: tbl_category,-> this subcategory

Comment: result already contains category_name and category_image from tbl_category

Comment: check api https://kalviaruvi.com/demoandroid/androidtest/api/api.php?get_home&api_key=cda11Uib7PLEA8pjKehSVfY0vdHsXI269J3MlqcGatWZBmxOgR

Comment: "cid":27,"category_name":"sdf","category_image":"3126-2022-08-24.jpeg"

Comment: i need this format 
[{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Electronics",
    "categorieslevelone": [{
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Mobiles",
        "categoriesleveltwo": [{
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Samsung",
            "parent_id": "2"
        }, {
            "id": "4",
            "name": "Nokia",
            "parent_id": "2"
        }]
    }]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247514/discussion-between-jay-raman-and-sushant-yadav).